# Relation between ergodicity and weakly mixing

Tags: ergodic-theory, mixing

A transformation $T$ on $X$ is **ergodic** iff for any two measurable sets
$U$ and $V$ holds: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} m(T^{-j}U\cap V)=m(U)m(V)$,

(or equivalently iff every invariant measurable
function is constant almost everywhere, or iff every T-invariant set has full measure or measure 0).

A transformation $T$ is called **weakly mixing** if for any two measurable sets
$U$ and $V$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} |m(T^{-j}U\cap V)-m(U)m(V)|=0$.

$T$ is weakly mixing if and only if $T\times T$ is ergodic.

It is known that weakly mixing implies that ergodicty, but the converse is not true, in general(consider for example irrational rotation of circle).

What conditions  imply that the converse holds?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what kind of answer you want. Maybe you could also look at the spectral characterization of each. Ergodicity is equivalent to the eigenvalue $1$ having eigenspace dimension $1$, and weak-mixing is equivalent to $1$ having eigenspace dimension $1$ and $1$ being the only eigenvalue; here I am talking about the natural operator $T$ induces on $L^2(X,\mu)$. For proofs of what I said, see Walters's book, page 48, theorem 1.26